# Discord avatar display code is not running

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, display, avatar

I wanted to use the command "-ava @(user)" to display the avatar of the specified user. I created this code but I'm not sure why when I type the command in discord where the bot is, nothing is returned. This is the following code for my discord bot:

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'ava',
  description: 'Provide user with certain avatar as requested.',
  execute(message, args) {
    if (args[0]) {
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (!user) return message.reply('Please mention a user to access their avatar');

      const otherIconEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${user.username}'s Avatar`)
        .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL);

      message.channel.send(otherIconEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    const myIconEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s avatar!`)
      .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL);

    message.channel.send(myIconEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

Comment: [user.displayAvatarURL()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) is a function that returns a link to the user's avatar image. you are trying to set the image to the function, instead of to the link it returns

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to put () after `displayAvatarURL` so it gives `displayAvatarURL ()` and if you want to make it animated you must put `displayAvatarURL ({dynamic: true})`